# To display last image uploaded instead of first one from mysql group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I upload images which are grouped by project name.

On the first page I display a project name with one image from that group.

It displays the first image uploaded from that group of images, and i am trying that the last image uploaded displays.

My code is:

```
$dbhostname="localhost";  
$dbusername="root";  
$dbpassword="";  
$db = "main_name";  
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhostname;dbname=$db", $dbusername, $dbpassword); 

foreach($dbh->query("SELECT *,COUNT(*)  
FROM images 
GROUP BY project_name ORDER BY img_timestamp DESC") as $row) { 
echo "Project Name: " . $row['project_name'];
echo "<br>";
echo $row['imagelink'];
}
```

For your reference my MySQL Table is:

```
Table name: images

id      project_name        imagelink       img_timestamp
1       Travier             image1          (timestamp of upload)
2       Travier             image2          (timestamp of upload)
3       Travier             image3          (timestamp of upload)
4       Travier             image4          (timestamp of upload)
5       Collosion           image1          (timestamp of upload)
6       Collosion           image2          (timestamp of upload)
7       Collosion           image3          (timestamp of upload)
```

Help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use A `SUBQUERY` AND `MAX` for that:

```
SELECT id, project_name, COUNT(*),
MAX(img_timestamp) AS img_timestamp,
(SELECT imagelink FROM images img WHERE img.project_name = images.project_name ORDER BY img_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS imagelink
FROM images GROUP BY project_name;
```

Please do keep in mind that using `*` will result in two columns having the name `img_timestamp` & `imagelink` another way could be using a different alias for the timestamp and imagelink.

Comment: Duh, obviously you need the `imagelink` :-) Sorry about that, I'll change the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try below queries both queries are working fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT Max(id)
  FROM images
  GROUP BY project_name
)

OR

SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE timestemp IN (
  SELECT Max(timestemp)
  FROM images
  GROUP BY project_name
)
```